# API endpoint to check latest .NET Core SDK version

Tags: .net, api, .net-core, sdk

I'm about to write a script to remove all `.NET Core SDKs`, except the latest one, from the local machine , thus I was curious whether there is any RESTful API endpoint which I could call to check the latest `.NET Core SDK` version available

Answer (score 2):

Try parsing https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/releases-index.json. (Try the "Raw" button to get a plain text version).

If you need even more information, that file links to a more detailed file (like https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.2/releases.json) which includes things like language version and installation URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The [.NET Github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/core/releases) contains the list of all releases. Probably you can use the Github's [get-latest-release API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release) to obtain the info